# Querying for the proportion of a certain element in a list

Tags: r, list

I have a data.table as follows:

```
library(data.table)  
DT <- fread(
    "A   B  C  D  E  F  iso   year   
     0   A   1   1  NA  NA  NLD   2009   
     1   Y   0   2  NA  NA  NLD   2009   
     0   Q   1   3  NA  NA  AUS   2011   
     1   NA  0   4  NA  NA  AUS   2011   
     0   0   1   7  NA  NA  NLD   2008   
     1   1   1   1  NA  NA  NLD   2008   
     0   1   1   3  NA  NA  AUS   2012   
     0   NA  1   NA  1  NA  ECU   2009   
     1   NA  0   NA  2  0   ECU   2009   
     0   NA  0   NA  3  0   BRA   2011   
     1   NA  0   NA  4  0   BRA   2011   
     0   NA  1   NA  7  NA  ECU   2008   
     1   NA  0   NA  1  0   ECU   2008   
     0   NA  0   NA  3  2   BRA   2012   
     1   NA  0   NA  4  NA  BRA   2012",
   header = TRUE
)
DT[, C1 := list(list(C)), by = iso]
```

Now I would like to test whether the proportion of 1's for every row in the created column `C1` is above 50%.

How would I go about this?

Desired output:

```
DT <- fread(
        "A   B  C  D  E  F  iso   year      C1   Outcome
         0   A   1   1  NA  NA  NLD   2009  c(1,0,1,1) 1 
         1   Y   0   2  NA  NA  NLD   2009  c(1,0,1,1) 1 
         0   Q   1   3  NA  NA  AUS   2011  c(1,0,1)   1 
         1   NA  0   4  NA  NA  AUS   2011  c(1,0,1)   1 
         0   0   1   7  NA  NA  NLD   2008  c(1,0,1,1) 1 
         1   1   1   1  NA  NA  NLD   2008  c(1,0,1,1) 1 
         0   1   1   3  NA  NA  AUS   2012  c(1,0,1)   1 
         0   NA  1   NA  1  NA  ECU   2009  c(1,0,1,0) 0 
         1   NA  0   NA  2  0   ECU   2009  c(1,0,1,0) 0 
         0   NA  0   NA  3  0   BRA   2011  c(0,0,0,0) 0 
         1   NA  0   NA  4  0   BRA   2011  c(0,0,0,0) 0 
         0   NA  1   NA  7  NA  ECU   2008  c(1,0,1,0) 0 
         1   NA  0   NA  1  0   ECU   2008  c(1,0,1,0) 0 
         0   NA  0   NA  3  2   BRA   2012  c(0,0,0,0) 0 
         1   NA  0   NA  4  NA  BRA   2012  c(0,0,0,0) 0",
       header = TRUE
    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can take `mean` for every element in `C1` to get ratio of 1's, compare it with 0.5 and assign values to new column `outcome`.

```
DT$outcome <- +(sapply(DT$C1, mean) > 0.5)

DT
#    A    B C  D  E  F iso year      C1 outcome
# 1: 0    A 1  1 NA NA NLD 2009 1,0,1,1       1
# 2: 1    Y 0  2 NA NA NLD 2009 1,0,1,1       1
# 3: 0    Q 1  3 NA NA AUS 2011   1,0,1       1
# 4: 1 <NA> 0  4 NA NA AUS 2011   1,0,1       1
# 5: 0    0 1  7 NA NA NLD 2008 1,0,1,1       1
# 6: 1    1 1  1 NA NA NLD 2008 1,0,1,1       1
# 7: 0    1 1  3 NA NA AUS 2012   1,0,1       1
# 8: 0 <NA> 1 NA  1 NA ECU 2009 1,0,1,0       0
# 9: 1 <NA> 0 NA  2  0 ECU 2009 1,0,1,0       0
#10: 0 <NA> 0 NA  3  0 BRA 2011 0,0,0,0       0
#11: 1 <NA> 0 NA  4  0 BRA 2011 0,0,0,0       0
#12: 0 <NA> 1 NA  7 NA ECU 2008 1,0,1,0       0
#13: 1 <NA> 0 NA  1  0 ECU 2008 1,0,1,0       0
#14: 0 <NA> 0 NA  3  2 BRA 2012 0,0,0,0       0
#15: 1 <NA> 0 NA  4 NA BRA 2012 0,0,0,0       0
```

Comment: Thank you very much Ronak! Is there any way to make the condition a robuster? For my actual data I for example need to check whether more than 10% of items in the list is below 300, and the range is different for every list.

Comment: @Tom If you have values other than 0 and 1 in `C1 ` you can do `+(sapply(DT$C1, function(x) sum(x == 1)/length(x)) > 0.5)` or `+(sapply(DT$C1, function(x) mean(x == 1)) > 0.5)` and replace 1 with whatever number you want to check.

Answer (score 0):

As it is a `data.table`, we can use `data.table` methods

```
DT[, outcome := unlist(lapply(C1, mean))]
```